# Linux Socket timeout works on WSL, but not on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, sockets, timeout, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I try to run a TCP client without a server. The idea is simply to periodically try to connect.
For this, the client tries to connect to port 1500 on localhost.

Piece of code:

```
    // Create socket
    if ((create_socket=socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, PF_UNSPEC)) > 0)
      printf ("Socket created\n");
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_port = htons (1500);
    inet_aton (argv[1], &address.sin_addr);

    // Connect to server
    connect ( create_socket,
                    (struct sockaddr *) &address,
                    sizeof (address));

    FD_ZERO(&fdset);
    FD_SET(create_socket, &fdset);
    tv.tv_sec = 2;             /* 2 seconds timeout */
    tv.tv_usec = 0;

    rv = select(create_socket + 1, NULL, &fdset, NULL, &tv);
    if (rv == 1)
    {
        int so_error;
        socklen_t len = sizeof so_error;

        getsockopt(create_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &so_error, &len);

        if (so_error == 0)
        {
          printf ("Connection with server (%s) established \n",
          inet_ntoa (address.sin_addr));
        }
        else
        {
          printf("Error on connect: unsuccessfull\n");
          close (create_socket);
          continue;
        }
    }
    else if (rv == 0)
    {
      printf("Timeout on connect\n");
      close (create_socket);
      continue;
    }
    else
    {
      printf("Error on connect\n");
      close (create_socket);
      continue;
    }
```

I've set it up in Ubuntu 18.04 on WSL. There, the code waits on `select` for the defined timeout of 2 seconds and returns appropriate return values. (0 on timeout, 1 on connect).
The return value of `connect` is -1 on WSL and VMware.
In Ubuntu 18 (VMware) there is no pause in that line. In any case, even without any server listening on that port, I get immediately a return value of 1.

Why is there this difference?

There is a similar behavior later on in that code:

```
    tv.tv_sec = 2;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;
    if (setsockopt(create_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (const char*)&tv, sizeof tv) < 0)
    {
      printf("Error on setsockopt SO_RCVTIMEO");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // INNER LOOP: Receive data
    do
    {
      size = recv(create_socket, buffer, BUF-1, 0);
      if( size > 0)
      {
        buffer[size] = '\0';
        printf ("Message received: %s\n", buffer);
      }
      else if (size == -1)
      {
      // on VMware, errno is 107 if there is no server, but coming to that line was not intended
        printf ("Timeout\n");
      }
      else //
      {
        printf("Server offline\n");
        // GO BACK TO OUTER LOOP and reconnect
        break;
      }
```

Here, in WSL the `recv` takes up to 2 seconds, while waiting for any incoming data. (But only if the aforementioned block (connect, select) indicates a valid connection)
In VMware I directly get the feedback. (even without connection)

Does it simply work on WSL by chance?

The argument contains the server IP and is 127.0.0.1.
`lsof` shows no connection.

---

Update 2020-11-18

Here's the full code as requested by [Bodo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64876204/linux-socket-timeout-works-on-wsl-but-not-on-ubuntu#comment114710440_64876204)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define BUF 1024
using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
  int create_socket;
  char *buffer =  (char*)malloc(BUF);
  struct sockaddr_in address;
  int size;
  int rv;
  struct timeval tv;
  fd_set fdset;

  // HERE STARTS THE OUTER LOOP - Connect and restart connection
  do
  {
    // Create socket
    if ((create_socket=socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, PF_UNSPEC)) > 0)
      printf ("Socket created\n");
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_port = htons (15000);
    inet_aton ("127.0.0.1", &address.sin_addr);

    // Connect to server
    int flags = fcntl(create_socket, F_GETFL, 0);
    if (flags == -1) return false;
    rv = connect ( create_socket,
                    (struct sockaddr *) &address,
                    sizeof (address));

    printf ("Connect. rv = %i\n", rv);

    if (rv == -1)
    {
      switch (errno)
      {
        case ECONNREFUSED:  printf ("errno = %i (ECONNREFUSED)\n", errno); break;
        default:  printf ("errno = %i (ECONNREFUSED)\n", errno); break;
      }

    }

    FD_ZERO(&fdset);
    FD_SET(create_socket, &fdset);

    tv.tv_sec = 2;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;
    rv = select(create_socket + 1, NULL, &fdset, NULL, &tv);
    if (rv == 1)
    {
        int so_error;
        socklen_t len = sizeof so_error;

        getsockopt(create_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &so_error, &len);

        if (so_error == 0)
        {
         printf ("Connection with server (%s) established \n",
          inet_ntoa (address.sin_addr));
        }
        else
        {
          printf("Error on connect: unsuccessfull\n");
          close (create_socket);
          continue;
        }
    }
    else if (rv == 0)
    {
      printf("Timeout on connect\n");
      close (create_socket);
      continue;
    }
    else
    {
      printf("Error on connect\n");
      close (create_socket);
      continue;
    }

    if (setsockopt(create_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (const char*)&tv, sizeof tv) < 0)
    {
      printf("Error on setsockopt SO_RCVTIMEO");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // INNER LOOP: Receive data
    do
    {
      size = recv(create_socket, buffer, BUF-1, 0);
      if( size > 0)
      {
        buffer[size] = '\0';
        printf ("Data received: %s\n", buffer);
      }
      else if (size == -1)
      {
        printf ("Timeout\n");
      }
      else //
      {
        printf("Server offline\n");
        // GO BACK TO OUTER LOOP and reconnect
        break;
      }
    } while (strcmp (buffer, "quit\n") != 0);
    close (create_socket);
  } while (strcmp (buffer, "quit\n") != 0);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

In WSL the output is

```
Socket created
Connect. rv = -1
errno = 111 (ECONNREFUSED)
```

then nothing for 2 seconds
afterwards

```
Timeout on connect
Socket created
Connect. rv = -1
errno = 111 (ECONNREFUSED)
```

and again nothing for 2 seconds ...

Output in VMware

```
Socket created
Connect. rv = -1
errno = 111 (ECONNREFUSED)
Connection with server (127.0.0.1) established 
Timeout
Timeout
Timeout
Timeout
```

Where no timeout is fulfilled.

The idea of timeout has been to try to connect on a regular basis, but not as fast as possible.

Comment: `fcntl` with  `F_GETFL` returns current flags "2" for both, WSL and VMware.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details: Clarify "appropriate return values". Which return value do you get? If select indicates a file descriptor, it means the requested operation on the file descriptor should not block. This can also mean that the operation will immedeiately return an error or EOF condition. You should check the return value of `connect`. "In VMware I directly get the feedback" Is there data available to receive? What feadback exactly do you get? In the case `size == -1` you should check `errno`. Please add all information **to the question**, not as comments.

Comment: @Bodo: Thanks. Update question as requested.

Comment: We cannot fully check or run your incomplete code. I suggest to create a [mre]. Explaining the preconditions and showing the output of your program for the different cases might also help to understand what's going on. If the return value of `connect` is -1 you should also check `errno`. Maybe you already get `errno==ECONNREFUSED` or other at this point. According to the man page, the behavior of `select` for writing and reading `SO_ERROR` is only defined for `errno==EINPROGRESS`. When no server is listening, the connection will be actively refused by a RST packet, so this is normally fast.

Comment: I've added the full code of the example including the check of errno.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously there is something wrong when `errno = 111 (ECONNREFUSED)` is followed by `Connection with server (127.0.0.1) established.`

When `connect` returns `-1` and `errno` is NOT `EINPROGRESS` you should **not** use `select`and `getsockopt(...SO_ERROR...)`. According to https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/connect.2.html, this is only documented for `EINPROGRESS`.

Both on real Linux and WSL you get `errno = 111 (ECONNREFUSED)` after a failed `connect`. I consider the timeout in WSL wrong as the error (conection refused) was already reported, so it does not make sense to wait for a result. But as the behavior is not specified, it may be implementation dependent.

If you want to have a delay before the next connection attempt, you should not use `select` but for example `sleep` followed by repeating the loop.

I suggest something like this:

```
    rv = connect ( create_socket,
                    (struct sockaddr *) &address,
                    sizeof (address));

    printf ("Connect. rv = %i\n", rv);

    if (rv == -1)
    {
      switch (errno)
      {
        case ECONNREFUSED:  printf ("errno = %i (ECONNREFUSED) %s\n", errno, strerror(errno)); break;
        default:  printf ("errno = %i (other) %s\n", errno, strerror(errno)); break;
      }
      if(errno != EINPROGRESS)
      {
        sleep(10); // chose a suitable delay before next connection attempt
        continue;
      }
    }
```